# How can a SVG sprite be made using independent SVG images?

Tags: svg, css-sprites

How can I combine SVG icons from http://raphaeljs.com/icons/ to make a CSS Sprite.

When I do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="30em" height="160em" viewBox="0 0 30 160" enable-background="new 0 0 30 160" xml:space="preserve"> 

<g id="icons">
    <g id="linkedin">
        <path d="M27.25,3.125h-22c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2v22c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2h22c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2v-22C29.25,4.021,28.354,3.125,27.25,3.125zM11.219,26.781h-4v-14h4V26.781zM9.219,11.281c-1.383,0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.117-2.5,2.5-2.5s2.5,1.119,2.5,2.5S10.602,11.281,9.219,11.281zM25.219,26.781h-4v-8.5c0-0.4-0.403-1.055-0.687-1.213c-0.375-0.211-1.261-0.229-1.665-0.034l-1.648,0.793v8.954h-4v-14h4v0.614c1.583-0.723,3.78-0.652,5.27,0.184c1.582,0.886,2.73,2.864,2.73,4.702V26.781z"
        />
    </g>

    <g id="github">
        <path d="M 500 800 M28.436,15.099c-1.201-0.202-2.451-0.335-3.466-0.371l-0.179-0.006c0.041-0.09,0.072-0.151,0.082-0.16c0.022-0.018,0.04-0.094,0.042-0.168c0-0.041,0.018-0.174,0.046-0.35c0.275,0.01,0.64,0.018,1.038,0.021c1.537,0.012,3.145,0.136,4.248,0.331c0.657,0.116,0.874,0.112,0.389-0.006c-0.491-0.119-1.947-0.294-3.107-0.37c-0.779-0.053-1.896-0.073-2.554-0.062c0.019-0.114,0.041-0.241,0.064-0.371c0.093-0.503,0.124-1.009,0.126-2.016c0.002-1.562-0.082-1.992-0.591-3.025c-0.207-0.422-0.441-0.78-0.724-1.104c0.247-0.729,0.241-1.858-0.015-2.848c-0.211-0.812-0.285-0.864-1.021-0.708C22.19,4.019,21.69,4.2,21.049,4.523c-0.303,0.153-0.721,0.391-1.024,0.578c-0.79-0.278-1.607-0.462-2.479-0.561c-0.884-0.1-3.051-0.044-3.82,0.098c-0.752,0.139-1.429,0.309-2.042,0.511c-0.306-0.189-0.75-0.444-1.067-0.604C9.973,4.221,9.473,4.041,8.847,3.908c-0.734-0.157-0.81-0.104-1.02,0.708c-0.26,1.003-0.262,2.151-0.005,2.878C7.852,7.577,7.87,7.636,7.877,7.682c-1.042,1.312-1.382,2.78-1.156,4.829c0.059,0.534,0.15,1.024,0.277,1.473c-0.665-0.004-1.611,0.02-2.294,0.064c-1.162,0.077-2.618,0.25-3.109,0.369c-0.484,0.118-0.269,0.122,0.389,0.007c1.103-0.194,2.712-0.32,4.248-0.331c0.29-0.001,0.561-0.007,0.794-0.013c0.07,0.237,0.15,0.463,0.241,0.678L7.26,14.759c-1.015,0.035-2.264,0.168-3.465,0.37c-0.901,0.151-2.231,0.453-2.386,0.54c-0.163,0.091-0.03,0.071,0.668-0.106c1.273-0.322,2.928-0.569,4.978-0.741l0.229-0.02c0.44,1.022,1.118,1.802,2.076,2.41c0.586,0.373,1.525,0.756,1.998,0.816c0.13,0.016,0.508,0.094,0.84,0.172c0.333,0.078,0.984,0.195,1.446,0.262h0.011c-0.009,0.006-0.017,0.01-0.025,0.016c-0.56,0.291-0.924,0.744-1.169,1.457c-0.11,0.033-0.247,0.078-0.395,0.129c-0.529,0.18-0.735,0.217-1.271,0.221c-0.556,0.004-0.688-0.02-1.02-0.176c-0.483-0.225-0.933-0.639-1.233-1.133c-0.501-0.826-1.367-1.41-2.089-1.41c-0.617,0-0.734,0.25-0.288,0.615c0.672,0.549,1.174,1.109,1.38,1.537c0.116,0.24,0.294,0.611,0.397,0.824c0.109,0.227,0.342,0.535,0.564,0.748c0.522,0.498,1.026,0.736,1.778,0.848c0.504,0.074,0.628,0.074,1.223-0.002c0.287-0.035,0.529-0.076,0.746-0.127c0,0.244,0,0.525,0,0.855c0,1.766-0.021,2.334-0.091,2.5c-0.132,0.316-0.428,0.641-0.716,0.787c-0.287,0.146-0.376,0.307-0.255,0.455c0.067,0.08,0.196,0.094,0.629,0.066c0.822-0.051,1.403-0.355,1.699-0.891c0.095-0.172,0.117-0.518,0.147-2.318c0.032-1.953,0.046-2.141,0.173-2.42c0.077-0.166,0.188-0.346,0.25-0.395c0.104-0.086,0.111,0.084,0.111,2.42c-0.001,2.578-0.027,2.889-0.285,3.385c-0.058,0.113-0.168,0.26-0.245,0.33c-0.135,0.123-0.192,0.438-0.098,0.533c0.155,0.154,0.932-0.088,1.356-0.422c0.722-0.572,0.808-1.045,0.814-4.461l0.003-2.004l0.219,0.021l0.219,0.02l0.036,2.621c0.041,2.951,0.047,2.994,0.549,3.564c0.285,0.322,0.572,0.5,1.039,0.639c0.625,0.188,0.813-0.102,0.393-0.605c-0.457-0.547-0.479-0.756-0.454-3.994c0.017-2.076,0.017-2.076,0.151-1.955c0.282,0.256,0.336,0.676,0.336,2.623c0,2.418,0.069,2.648,0.923,3.07c0.399,0.195,0.511,0.219,1.022,0.221c0.544,0.002,0.577-0.006,0.597-0.148c0.017-0.115-0.05-0.193-0.304-0.348c-0.333-0.205-0.564-0.467-0.709-0.797c-0.055-0.127-0.092-0.959-0.117-2.672c-0.036-2.393-0.044-2.502-0.193-2.877c-0.201-0.504-0.508-0.902-0.897-1.166c-0.101-0.066-0.202-0.121-0.333-0.162c0.161-0.016,0.317-0.033,0.468-0.055c1.572-0.209,2.403-0.383,3.07-0.641c1.411-0.543,2.365-1.445,2.882-2.724c0.046-0.114,0.092-0.222,0.131-0.309l0.398,0.033c2.051,0.173,3.706,0.42,4.979,0.743c0.698,0.177,0.831,0.198,0.668,0.105C30.666,15.551,29.336,15.25,28.436,15.099zM22.422,15.068c-0.233,0.512-0.883,1.17-1.408,1.428c-0.518,0.256-1.33,0.451-2.25,0.544c-0.629,0.064-4.137,0.083-4.716,0.026c-1.917-0.188-2.991-0.557-3.783-1.296c-0.75-0.702-1.1-1.655-1.039-2.828c0.039-0.734,0.216-1.195,0.679-1.755c0.421-0.51,0.864-0.825,1.386-0.985c0.437-0.134,1.778-0.146,3.581-0.03c0.797,0.051,1.456,0.051,2.252,0c1.886-0.119,3.145-0.106,3.61,0.038c0.731,0.226,1.397,0.834,1.797,1.644c0.18,0.362,0.215,0.516,0.241,1.075C22.808,13.699,22.675,14.517,22.422,15.068zM12.912,11.762c-1.073-0.188-1.686,1.649-0.863,2.587c0.391,0.445,0.738,0.518,1.172,0.248c0.402-0.251,0.62-0.72,0.62-1.328C13.841,12.458,13.472,11.862,12.912,11.762zM19.425,11.872c-1.073-0.188-1.687,1.647-0.864,2.586c0.392,0.445,0.738,0.519,1.173,0.247c0.401-0.25,0.62-0.72,0.62-1.328C20.354,12.569,19.985,11.971,19.425,11.872zM16.539,15.484c-0.023,0.074-0.135,0.184-0.248,0.243c-0.286,0.147-0.492,0.096-0.794-0.179c-0.187-0.169-0.272-0.258-0.329-0.081c-0.053,0.164,0.28,0.493,0.537,0.594c0.236,0.094,0.405,0.097,0.661-0.01c0.254-0.106,0.476-0.391,0.476-0.576C16.842,15.303,16.595,15.311,16.539,15.484zM16.222,14.909c0.163-0.144,0.2-0.44,0.044-0.597s-0.473-0.133-0.597,0.043c-0.144,0.206-0.067,0.363,0.036,0.53C15.865,15.009,16.08,15.034,16.222,14.909z"
        />
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

the SVG icons overlap. How can I modify these to have an offset between two icons? 
For instance, the one similar to http://dbushell.com/demos/css-sprites/sprite.svg

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the 2nd M command to m command.
"M" means absolute position, "m" means relative position.
so,
<M 500 800 ｍ28.436,15.099c-1.201-0.202-2.…